# Power BI Insert values in table from UI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Couldnt find something similar from my search, but here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a metadata table in snowflake which should hold a business freeze date that is manually decided by business. I am trying to get to a solution where the business can manually insert the date from power bi online and get the table update.

Anyone had something similar to deal with?

Thanks

Comment: Power BI is a reporting tool, not a database editor.

Comment: It does have the possibility of writeback, managed to do so with power automate where I can write back into an excel spreadsheet, but for the moment it does not support a snowflake connector, so was wondering if there is another option. Your comment seems to be very simplistic and minimising the power house that power bi is :)

Comment: This page implies that Power Automate talks to Snowflake OK. Vendors don't always tell the truth :) https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/power_apps_snowflake/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0 Up to you whether you want a neat Power Apps plugin over the top

Comment: Power BI absolutely does not have writeback capability natively. I am fully aware you can hack some things together with Power Automate flows or Power Apps - but you also quite possibly need to maintain these quirky solutions for a long time. Just because you can, doesn’t mean you should. In any event, StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. Good luck.